# Previously working SAGE install broke

Tags: python, ubuntu, sage

Sage was working for me about a month ago. I had not used it until yesterday, and when I tried using the sage command in my Ubuntu 12.04 terminal I receive the following error

```
/usr/bin/sage: line 118: cd: /usr/lib/sage: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/sage: cannot determine SAGE_ROOT directory
```

I tried everything I could think of and google. I have tried reinstalling libc6-i386 and the ia32-libs but that does not seem to be the reason. My computer is otherwise working well without any other programs (perhaps I've yet to notice) malfunctioning. It doesn't seem like this is a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue.
Of course, I checked both locations and the files are there. I have also reinstalled sage a few times, and the issue remains.
Thank you!

Comment: what does `ls /usr/lib/sage` from the command line give?

Comment: Hmm.  Typically Sage isn't in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/lib`. Have you tried downloading Sage to a "normal" directory and seeing if it works there?  Just a random idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run sage this way:

```
export SAGE_ROOT=<dir where sage archive was extracted, e.g. /home/daniel/sage>
sage
```

If it works, you should find why SAGE_ROOT var doesn't set. If not, post error message if it changes.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Apparently even though the file was there it was not supposed to be that one. I think my previous version installed a link of sage in /usr/bin/sage and I had added a .bashrc SAGE_ROOT to that location, but now, I removed everything (which for some reason package manager failed to do including some other folders of configurations) and reinstalled and it worked!